# Miscrosoft365R - pluck list contents

Tags: r, list, nested-lists, microsoft365r

I have a nested list of what appears to be a Microsft365R object called an 'R6' object.

I am able to output the email contents to the console using emails[[1]] - but cannot seem to unnest this or pluck the contents to a dataframe. I would to be able to get a dataframe where I have two columns of just the subject and body.

I'd really like to be able to map through the list and pluck any values into the body that are just for a specific string from start to finish on a grepl() match for a pattern using regex. Is this even possible with this type of object? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `emails$list_items()`? Or perhaps `emails@list_items()`? Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R) the object may have a 'built-in' method of extracting the contents as a dataframe